# Automating UDP connection from constructor With Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, udp, task, scheduler

In the constructor of the main form of an application I have:

```
    public GUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Connect();
    }
```

Here is Connect():

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        string IP = "###.###.#.#"
        int port = 4000;

        credentials_ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);

        if (credentials_socket == null)
        {
            credentials_socket = new UdpClient(port);
        }

        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("LOGIN");
        credentials_socket.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, credentials_ipep);

        string received;

        try
        {
            received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(credentials_socket.Receive(ref credentials_ipep));
            MessageBox.Show("Yay Server Connected!");
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Server Not Running!");
            return;
        }
    }
```

The main method of the program is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new GUI());
    }
```

My application gets stuck on the line `received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(credentials_socket.Receive(ref credentials_ipep));`

When I remove `Connect()` from the constructor, and instead call it on a button click on the main form (GUI), the code works perfectly, I am able to see the messageboxes telling me if the server is running or not.

Is there some sort of network initialization that needs to be done at the completion of the constructor that I am not seeing? The reason I want to place `Connect()` in the constructor is so that I can start the application from Windows Task Scheduler instead of manually clicking `Connect()`.